# Ajax request to Paypal

Tags: jquery, ajax, paypal

Hello i'm trying to make the user visit a Paypal url in the background, but it doesnt seem to work.
This is the code

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=B47NFTANZL5S6",
    succus: function() {
        alert('succus');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('error');
    },
    complete: function() {
        alert('Complete');
    }
});
```

You can click this link [Paypal link](http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=B47NFTANZL5S6) and it will add a item in the checkout.
But cant make it work via a ajax request.

Comment: For security reasons, browsers tend to unilaterally block any ajax-calls being made to URLs outside the domain that served the current page. [Read more (keyword: cross-domain)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @PaulRoth, It makes sense...

Comment: Alright, i found an alternative by using the window.open() method. Thanks